# In Crystal, how can you tell if a file is text or binary?

Tags: crystal-lang

If you have 2 files, one text and the other binary, is it possible to determine which is a text file and which is a binary using Crystal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose, it's impossible, using native Crystal. To determine type of a file, it needs to read a part of a file and guess its type on the content basis. This can be a tricky part, so if you need a relatively reliable solution, I'd suggest invoke `file --mime-type -b <file>` from Crystal and parse the output, though it makes mistakes sometimes too.

Additionally you can use [crystal-mime](https://github.com/spalger/crystal-mime) shard to handle the output of `file` command.

Comment: `spalger/crystal-mime` doesn't use the `file` command and doesn't provide any method for matching byte patterns either.

Comment: @JohannesMüller, as I can see from the description, it completely relies on file's extension. So, you can take a .jpg file, change it's extension to .mp3, and `crystal-mime` will think it is `mp3` now. Not very reliable.

Comment: Exactly. But depending on the use case, this might be entirely sufficient.

Comment: Looking at the byte pattern at the beginning of a file is more advanced but still not fully reliable.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Magic Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Magic_numbers_in_files) to detect binary files otherwise it could be a plain text file.

> is it possible to determine which is a text file and which is a binary using Crystal?

If you assume "binary" is an [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) file, then you can try this:

```
def filetype(filename)
  unless File.file?(filename)
    puts "Isn't a file!"
    return
  end
  File.open(filename, "r") do |f|
    case f.gets(4)
    when "\x7FELF" then puts "Is an ELF binary file"
    # when "GIF8" then puts "Is a GIF"
    # when "\x25\x50\x44\x46" then puts "Is a PDF"
    # ... and so on
    else
      puts "Probably is a plain text file"
    end
  end
end

File.write("plain.txt", "Plain Text File")

filetype("plain.txt")   # => Probably is a plain text file
filetype("/usr/bin/ls") # => Is an ELF binary file
filetype("/dev/sda")    # => Isn't a file!
```

This works even on non-executable ELF files (without `x` permission). If you want to detect executable files then use [`File.executable?`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/master/File.html#executable%3F%28path%29%3ABool-class-method).

Demo here: https://carc.in/#/r/44a2

Also `file` is a nice command that uses [`libmagic`](https://github.com/threatstack/libmagic) under the hood to detect magic numbers and get the right file type. You can do some bindings to `libmagic` using Crystal as well, so you don't need to specify all magic numbers by yourself.

Comment: The problem here is that this can be mimicked by any file. I.e you can write a file matching '\x7FELF'–which is what makes this so hard.